# Simple/homeworkish questions getting closed as 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few of these kind of questions asking a very simple thing that would be easily googlable. They are also probably homework motivated. Here is an [example](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/roughly-how-much-co2-is-generated-per-kwh-of-electricity-generated).

What should we do about these kinds of questions? I think they should be closed, but could we create a homework type flag/reason for closing similar to the one there is in Physics SE? Or could there be a flag simply stating: 'This is a very simple issue and you haven't been able to google the answer somehow'. Currently my example question is being closed as 'too broad' which it certainly isn't.

Answer (score 2):

As one of those who voted to close the question you refer to, there are a limited number of reasons available to us for closing a question and sometimes the reasons available do not enable us to truly state the reason why we think the question should be closed.

Like you, I would like to see more options available to us.

I think this site should both options that you mention:

- A homework flag/reason
- And flag/ reason stating something like, "Not enough research is
  evident in the question".

Answer (score 1):

If homework questions are not living up to the standard of the [homework question policy](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-earth-science-stack-exchange/317), then close them as off-topic, but please leave a comment to give the asker a chance to salvage their question (and link to the policy so they know is expected of their question).  If poor homework questions become too common we can look into a custom close reason to better describe them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question will usually be **downvoted** and.or **closed** as too broad or off topic because most questions ***can*** be just typed up into google to find an answer. Stackexchange is meant to be a site for questions google *cannot* answer, so people ask them here.

And as @Fred mentioned, a flag for homework-ish questions would be helpful for our site, because it would minimize the number of **off-topic questions** from new users.